# In App Review opens only once when testing for the same account

Tags: android

So I integrated In App Review for my app

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#launch-review-flow

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test

uploaded to Internal Testing on Google Play

downloaded the app from Google Play

pressed button to rate and it displayed In App Review dialog

I closed without submitting the rating

then I try to press the button to rate again but nothing happens, there is some visual effect like it tries to open something but close it very fast

reinstalling doesn't help to open this rate dialog again

the only thing which helps is to change google account (add to the internal testing and to the device)

what is the problem here?

it should not display rate dialog only if I submitted the rating before but I didn't and it doesn't open again for the same account, only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I found the way to fix it:

Clear the data and cache of Google Play before launching In App Review flow

After that it works again.

And we have to do it every time if In App Review dialog was shown before

The issue is same for emulators and real devices